# How to use TreeView.Tag = object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myData = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myData.Add(1, "England");
myData.Add(2, "Canada");
myData.Add(3, "Australia");
myTreeView.Node[0].Tag = myData;
```

Then I want to get this object, how should I do it ?
Like:

```
string str = new string();
str = myTreeView.Node[0].Tag[2]; // "str" should be equal to "Canada"
myTreeView.Node[0].Tag[1] = "Spain";
str = myTreeView.Node[0].Tag[1]; // now "str" is equal to "Spain"
```

Second question - what will return this expression:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myData = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myData.Add(1, "England");
myData.Add(2, "Canada");
myData.Add(3, "Australia");

string str1 = new string();
str = myData[4]; // there isn't such a key as 4
```

Exception or null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Control.Tag` is typed as `object` so you'll need to cast it to access it as a `Dictionary<int, string>`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = (Dictionary<int, string>)myTreeView.Node[0].Tag;
string str = dict[2];
```

And similarly to set a value:

```
var dict = (Dictionary<int, string>)myTreeView.Node[0].Tag;
dict[1] = "Spain";
```

If you try to access a non-existent key, a `KeyNotFoundException` will be thrown. You can check if the dictionary contains a given key using `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey`:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    var value = dict[key];
}
else
{
}
```

TryGetValue does the lookup and sets the given variable to the value (it it exists) in a single call, so is usually preferred.

```
string value;
if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    //use value
}
else { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any chance to check whether is there such key, like: if dict contains key=4 then {.....} else {....} ?

Comment: @Lee: why cast to Dictionary<int, string>? is it possible use a custom class?

Comment: @Amir - `Dictionary<int, string>` is the type used in the question but yes you can use any type.

Comment: @Lee: Thanks for the tip, I had a mistake in my code. I found it.

Answer (score 1):

> Exception or null ?

Well, you could just try it out yourself or [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (it throws an exception).

Also, your code will not compile as posted.  `Tag` is a way to associate arbitrary data with an object.  As a result, its type is `object`, so you will need to cast it before using it as you do.

If your code ever becomes unwieldy due to overuse of the `Tag` property I would suggest creating your own node type which inherits from the default `TreeNode` (or whatever it is) and populating your tree view with that type of object instead.

Answer (score 0):

The tightest means for addressing the properties of a node tag is:

```
((TagType)node_identity.Tag).TagProperty = value;
```

Thus the tag properties of the *parent* node can be addressed so:

```
((TagType)node_identity.Parent.Tag).TagProperty = value;
```

The tag properties of a *child* node can be addressed so:

```
((TagType)node_identity.Nodes[index_of_child].Tag).TagProperty = value;
```

And as each *Nodes[index_identifier]* resolves to a node, the tag properties of more remote child nodes can be addressed so:

```
((TagType)node_identity.Nodes[index_of_child].Nodes[index_of_further_child].Tag).TagProperty = value;
```

Etc.

As far as the assumable objects of Tagging your dictionary are concerned... assuming your purposes require the same integer-string associations everywhere, I would instead simply store the integer key value to your Tag field, and pull the associated string from perhaps a global List<string> DictionaryStrings object. Then you could store only the integer index value to your Tags; and only the string values to your List<string>.

You would then read your Tag values as follows:

```
((int)node_identity.Tag)
```

Given these assumptions, you would instead populate your infrastructure so:

```
List<string> DictionaryStrings = new List<string>;
DictionaryStrings.Add("Canada"); // etc.
```

Then you would read the tag to pull your DictionaryString from the index value stored to your Tags as follows:

```
string DictionaryString = DictionaryStrings[((int)node_identity.Tag)];
```

Your error message is a consequence of addressing a prospective member of your dictionary which you have not yet added (at that execution point) to your dictionary. Fully populate the List or dictionary first; then only address *valid* indexes *belonging* to the List/dictionary.

Comment: I also concur with Ed S's suggestion to consider subclassing TreeNode — especially if you are dynamically populating your TreeView. In fact, I would say that subclassing TreeNode will make coding so much more straightforward, that it is absolutely the preferable approach for programmatically populated TreeViews.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Just tried subclassing TreeNode and was surprised how much casting was required. No implicit conversions. I'm not sure I haven't overlooked something... that has made subclassing more of a nightmare than it should be. But the way things are looking right now, I'd stick to the Tag implementation unless some other consideration swings the other way.